# unable to convert array to list using later package

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to do scheduling using the later package. I am facing problem while adding the dayofweek(). i have an array with days that i want to recur the schedule. I am unable to do it while it takes only first element of the array. please guide me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

```
let array = [2,4,5,6]
let schedule = later.parse.recur().every(10).minute().after(st).time().before(et).time().on(parseint(array.join()e)).dayOfWeek();
let tdate = later.schedule(schedule).next(20);
```

Comment: The problem with this kind of syntax is debugging. I've never used this library, and looks very hard to debug... Are you sure you need this library ? Using RxJs could do the trick, with `interval` for instance, and a lot more people would be able to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for this by using a function.

```
 function r(item) {
     return item ;
    }


let array = [2,4,5,6]
let schedule = later.parse.recur().every(10).minute().after(st).time().before(et).time().on(r(array)).dayOfWeek();
let tdate = later.schedule(schedule).next(20);
```